# Running a window again that has been destroyed in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

I have created a window ("Main") that contains a button ("Create") that triggers another window("Form") upon clicking. This newly-created window contains some entry fields and a button ("Submit"). This newly-created window should be closed after the "Submit" button is clicked. And also the same window("Form") should be created again when the button "Create" is clicked. How can this be achieved? I have created different classes for each window and invoked their objects to create a window.

Comment: Better provide a [mre].

Comment: call `Form` in both `main` and `create`?